# What are the candles outside in Denmark about?

Tags: local-customs, identify-this, denmark

There are candles out in Denmark all over the place, lit, even during the daytime - mostly placed next to doorways and entranceways.

They look like little lanterns - almost like these:

[image]

If this was anywhere else you might assume someone had died there but that's obviously not the case here.

What are these candles all about?

Comment: http://www.lutheranchurch.dk/nc/liturgy-and-worship/festivals-and-traditions/candlemas/?print=1   Hence, you may find concerts and church services on February 4 in your area.

Comment: @gerrit Yes - "at stille træskoene".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hygge (pronounced hue-gah) is a Danish word that is a feeling or mood that comes taking genuine pleasure in making ordinary, every day moments more meaningful, beautiful or special.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hygge

Candles are an integral part of hygge, and the Danes love to burn candles all year round. Some people say that the concept of hygge started somewhere, with a source of light in the middle, and people huddling together, to keep warm.

http://simplydanishliving.com/creating-hygge-scented-candles/

“Danes take hygge lighting and design very seriously,” agrees the British Ambassador to Denmark, Vivien Life, who had a crash course in hygge when she took up the role in 2012. “Lights are used to make spaces feel relaxed and warm, and you see a lot of low-slung dining-room table lamps as well out here.”

Hope that solves it.

Comment: As a Dane, I will confidently say that this standard soundbite doesn't connect to the photo in the question in the least. Candles _in doorways and entranceways_ are not particularly connected to "hygge". In fact the question has me stupefied, since I have never noticed any particular placement of candles in such positions, but Gayot's suggestion that the OP may have run into a (posisbly local or regional) _kyndelmisse_ tradition sounds plausible.

Comment: I agree with Henning Makholm, I am also a bit puzzled that this should be a general thing. To me, for "hygge" candles indoors seem more likely. But it looks nice though!